# Server-side input validation with Quasar (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, validation, asp.net-core, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm looking for a reusable solution for server side input validation with [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev).
I use the [`q-input`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input) field. There are 2 props that can be used for the error output `error` and `error-message`. My server response on a validation error is a 400 response with this json

```
{
  errors: { username: ['Username is to long.', 'User not valid'] },
  title: 'One or more validation errors occurred.',
  status: 400,
  traceId: '80000005-0000-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb'
}
```

I am currently using this logic, but I cannot move it to a mixin because I need access to the error field. The full example is available here [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-rain-dc78o?file=/src/pages/Index.vue)

```
<q-input
  v-model="username"
  filled
  label="Username *"
  :error-message="getErrorForField('username')"
  :error="isErrorForField('username')"
/>
```

```js
getErrorForField(field) {
  if (!this.errors) {
    return ''
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(this.errors)
  const key = keys.find(
    element => element.toLowerCase() === field.toLowerCase()
  )
  if (this.errors[key]) {
    return this.errors[key].join('\r\n')
  }
},
isErrorForField(field) {
  if (!this.errors) {
    return false
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(this.errors)
  const key = keys.find(
    element => element.toLowerCase() === field.toLowerCase()
  )
  if (this.errors[key]) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution with the new vue3 composition-api. I now have a reusable logic.

***MyComponent.vue***

```
<template>
<q-input
  v-model="username"
  filled
  label="Username *"
  :error-message="getErrorForField('username')"
  :error="isErrorForField('username')"
/>
</template>

<script>
import { validationHelper } from 'src/helper/validationHelper'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup () {
    const { showValidationError, setValidationErrors, getValidationErrors, hasValidationErrors } = validationHelper()
    return {
      showValidationError,
      setValidationErrors,
      getValidationErrors,
      hasValidationErrors
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async add () {
      try {
        //axios request
      } catch (error) {
        this.setValidationErrors(error.response.data.errors)
        this.showValidationError()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***validationHelper.js***

```js
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export function validationHelper () {
  const errors = ref([])

  function getValidationErrorMessages (field) {
    if (!errors.value) {
      return []
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(errors.value)
    const key = keys.find(element => element.toLowerCase() === field.toLowerCase())
    if (errors.value[key]) {
      return errors.value[key]
    }
    return []
  }

  function getValidationErrors (field) {
    const errors = getValidationErrorMessages(field)
    if (errors.length !== 0) {
      return errors.join('\r\n')
    }
    return ''
  }

  function hasValidationErrors (field) {
    if (getValidationErrorMessages(field).length !== 0) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  function setValidationErrors (payload) {
    errors.value = payload
  }

  function showValidationError () {
    this.$q.notify({
      type: 'negative',
      message: 'Validation failure',
      caption: 'please check the inputs'
    })
  }

  return {
    showValidationError,
    setValidationErrors,
    getValidationErrors,
    hasValidationErrors
  }
}
```